# async task deadlock when call ExecuteAsync() function

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, async-await, youtube-api

I have problem when I trying to return task result from task `async` function my function:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Run()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "API Key",


  ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "anwar jibawi"; // Replace with your search term.
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

        // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    string thumbnail = searchResult.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default__.Url;
                    videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1}) {2}", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId, thumbnail));
                    break;

                case "youtube#channel":
                    channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#playlist":
                    playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                    break;
            }
        }

        return videos;
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
```

here I'm calling async function:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Task<IEnumerable<string>> task = new Search().Run();
        task.Wait();//if remove this line it will work fine but without any result
        var x = task.Result;//if remove this line it will work fine but without any result
        return View();
    }
```

Why its hanging when I call `task.Wait()` or `task.Reslut`

Comment: Why not change the method to `Task<ActionResult>` and `await` the task?

Comment: How can I return my IEnumerable<string> Video if I changed the method?
Is there away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is an ASP.NET application, [you shouldn't use `.Result`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/08/28/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context/) (or `.Wait()`) as it will result in deadlock (as you've found out)

Instead, change your Index method to this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{

    var x = await new Search().Run();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This is true thanks a lot, but edit your answer to add missing '()' for the new instance   await new Search().Run(), Thanks again

Comment: `await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync()` should also have a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on it to protect against this, because it doesn't require the context in the continuation and doesn't know if the caller will do something silly like synchronously wait.

Comment: Yes your right @GeorgeHelyar I added for my code thanks.